# .NET Core 6 webapp Pass Through User Credentials to SQL

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, iis

I realize this has been asked before, but I feel like I have read the entire internet and still can't resolve my issue. Maybe you can see my mistake? I have created a .NET Core 6 web application and am using IIS (version 10) to host it. It uses a SQL Server database that I would like windows authentication to manage read/write permissions. What is happening is that it is passing the hosted machine credentials to SQL Server and not the user IE "domain\servername$" instead of "domain\kirstie.ballance".

**startup.cs**

[image]

Appsettings.Json

[image]

Connection Sting

[image]

web.config

[image]

IIS Authentication
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#iis

Have you tried enabling Windows Authentication in WebConfig

Comment: I have yes. Thanks for the suggestion thought :)

Comment: At this stage i am lost also, try this maybe it helps Windows Environment Configuration.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#windows-environment-configuration

Comment: Have you tried using `Trusted_Connection=true;` **or** `Integrated Security=SSPI;`? These are either-or options, you don't normally use both together. Ref: [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Connection String property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring)

Comment: Do you have multiple settings files, e.g.: `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json`, etc.? Which `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is the server configured to use (and so which settings file is it using)?

Comment: I have tried Trusted_Connection=true Trusted_Connection=yes and Integrated Security=SSPI; in turn. I have multiple appsettings.json files yes, but I have confirmed that it uses appsettings.Production.json

Comment: Is there any code about Impersonation just like this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation.

Comment: I did try that, but it just kept closing my app. Like, I would start the website and wait for it to come up, but the console window would just report that it was done doing what it needed to do, with no browser popping up. I couldn't even stick a break point in, to debug it.

Comment: After my research, I want to confirm some issues. Although you have tried various Trusted_Connection. Have you tested Trusted_Connection=true but remove Integrated Security. I'm not sure it works but please give it a try. Also, I saw about launchSettings.json file according to a tutorial. Can you show the relevant settings? Refer to: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-core/.